# How to update a relation property in Neo4J Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following Neo4J Cypher query:

```
MATCH (u:User {uid: $userId}) 
UNWIND $contextNames as contextName 
MERGE (context:Context {name:contextName.name,by:u.uid,uid:contextName.uid}) 
ON CREATE SET context.timestamp=$timestamp 
MERGE (context)-[:BY{timestamp:$timestamp}]->(u)
```

The last string always creates a new relation between the `context` and the `u` node. However, what if I just want to update it? How do I integrate this logic into the query above?

Do I have to add `WITH context,u` before the `MERGE` and then add `rel:BY` into the query?

Or do `MATCH (context)-[rel:BY....` and then update the `rel`?

Just looking for the most efficient "best practices" way to do that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible situation which might occur:

1. A relation between `context` and `u` is already present
2. A relation between `context` and `u` is not yet present (this will happen when `context`was just created by merge)

When you run the following line

```
MERGE (context)-[:BY{timestamp:$timestamp}]->(u)
```

Neo4j will check if there is already a relation `BY` in place between `context` and `u` with the given timestamp value. If yes, no new relation will be created. I guess that the timestamp is not a proper identifier for matching a relation, especially since you write that you want to update it. Therefore, I recommend to update the query in the following way:

```
MATCH (u:User {uid: $userId}) 
UNWIND $contextNames as contextName 
MERGE (context:Context {name:contextName.name,by:u.uid,uid:contextName.uid}) 
ON CREATE SET context.timestamp=$timestamp 
MERGE (context)-[by:BY]->(u)
SET by.timestamp=$timestamp
```

This way, a relation will be created if not already present. Either way, the timestamp will be set to the specified value.

Comment: Ok, I encountered a very strange problem with this, please, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54337195/weird-neo4j-cypher-behavior-on-setting-relationship-properties