# Weird Neo4J Cypher behavior on setting relationship properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a Cypher request for Neo4J of this kind:

```
MATCH (u:User {uid: $userId}) 
UNWIND $contextNames as contextName 
MERGE (context:Context {name:contextName.name,by:u.uid,uid:contextName.uid}) 
ON CREATE SET context.timestamp=$timestamp 
MERGE (context)-[by:BY]->(u) 
SET by.timestamp = $timestamp
```

My params are:

```
{
 "userId": "15229100-b20e-11e3-80d3-6150cb20a1b9",
 "contextNames": [
  {
    "uid": "822e2580-1f5e-11e9-9ed0-5b93e8900a78",
    "name": "fnas"
  }
 ],
 "timestamp": "1912811921129"
}
```

That query above sets 8 parameters because I have (probably) 8 other relationships of the :BY type in relation to that `u`. Which seems to me illogical as it should only find one relationship between a concrete `context` and a concrete `u`, create it if it doesn't exist, and set the property for it

However, when I do this:

```
 MATCH (u:User {uid: $userId}) 
 UNWIND $contextNames as contextName 
 MERGE (context:Context {name:contextName.name,by:u.uid,uid:contextName.uid}) 
 ON CREATE SET context.timestamp=$timestamp 
 MERGE (context)-[:BY{timestamp:$timestamp}]->(u)
```

It either creates a relationship (if the one with the same timestamp doesn't exist) or it simply doesn't do anything (which seems to be the right behavior).

What is the reason for this discrepancy? A bug in Neo4J?

Comment: Which version of Neo4j are you using?

Comment: I use version 3.3.3

Comment: If you run the following, how many nodes do you get back? `MATCH (context:Context {name:"fnas",by:"15229100-b20e-11e3-80d3-6150cb20a1b9",uid:"822e2580-1f5e-11e9-9ed0-5b93e8900a78"})  RETURN context`? Also what does this return? `MATCH (u:User {uid: "15229100-b20e-11e3-80d3-6150cb20a1b9"})<-[by:BY]-(context:Context {name:"fnas",by:"15229100-b20e-11e3-80d3-6150cb20a1b9",uid:"822e2580-1f5e-11e9-9ed0-5b93e8900a78"}) RETURN count(by)`

Comment: @InverseFalcon so my db params are a bit different, but basically i only have one `fnas` context (I checked that thinking it could be the error) — verified by `MATCH (context:Context {name:"fnas") RETURN context` and also this `MATCH (u:User {uid: "15229100-b20e-11e3-80d3-6150cb20a1b9"})<-[by:BY]-(context:Context {name:"fnas") RETURN count(by)` returns 3 which is 1 more than I'm supposed to have (and it shows only 2 on the neo4j browser graph.

Comment: Just to add: the problem with this is not necessarily that 8 parameters are set but that because there are somehow 8 `by` relationships in the database then later when I call `WITH u, context` after that I get `match u, context` 8 times also. Is this normal behavior if there's multiple `by` relations? Will it also consider there are 8 `contexts`?

Comment: What happens when you add a `RETURN context, by, u` to the query? Are there multiple nodes/relations returned?

Comment: @DmitryParanyushkin In Cypher, multiple matches (in this case, caused by multiple :BY relationships) will result in multiple rows, even if those rows have the same nodes. Operations execute per row, so yes you may be executing this redundantly, and this is expected behavior. You'll want to manage the cardinality by using aggregations or usage of DISTINCT.